# Symfony: No route found for "GET http://localhost:8000/biens/Mon-premier-bien-1" (from "http://localhost:8000/")

Tags: php, symfony

as you can see, this is the show method in my PropertyController:

```
/**
 * @Route("/biens/{slug}-{id<\d+>}", name="property.show", requirements={"slug": "[a-z0-9\-]*"})
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($slug, $id): Response
{
    $property = $this->repository->find($id);
    return $this->render('property/show.html.twig', [
        'property' => $property,
        'current_menu' => 'properties'
    ]);
}
```

and in my home.html.twig file, this is a part of my code:

```
<a href="{{ path('property.show', {slug: property.slug, id: property.id}) }}">{{ property.title }}</a>
```

however I don't really understand why I get this error message when I try to access the link eventhough hovering over the link I can see my url.

Comment: Maybe `"[A-Za-z0-9\-]*"` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try it:

```
@Route("/biens/{slug}/{id}", name="property.show", requirements={"slug": "[a-z0-9\-]*", "id": "\d+"})
```

Comment: I already dit it but it's doesn't work, weird

Comment: Can I see the error?

Comment: May be "slug": " [a-z0-9]+"

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/biens/{slug}-{id}",
 *     name="property.show",
 *     requirements={
 *         "slug": "[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*",
 *         "id": "\d+"
 *     }
 * )
 * @return Response
 */
```

You need to add A-Z in your regex because of "**M**on-premier-bien-1"